# Drag and drop a popup text box in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a little program in WPF where I click on a button and a popup text box arrive. I would like to make this movable - drag and drop.

In the code I have created an object for a textbox named `x`, and used the command `x.AllowDrop = true;`, but without success.

I have tried MSN, Youtube and other sources, but without success.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    TextBox x = new TextBox();      
    x.Name = "new_textboxqq";       
    x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;     
    x.Text = "asfsadfasfsadfasff";                          

    x.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;   
    x.Background = Brushes.Yellow;      
    x.AcceptsReturn = true
        x.Margin = new Thickness(5, 10, 0, 0);  

    x.AllowDrop = true;

    HouseCanvas.Children.Add(x);            
    this.AllowDrop = true;

    Canvas.SetLeft(x, 20);                  
    Canvas.SetTop(x, 20);                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Drag and Drop` is a data transfer technique. From one control or files to another control or window.

If you need to move your control inside window, you need using mouse events: `MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseMove`. [Look this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416734/moving-a-textbox-with-mouse)

Answer (score 0):

You want to drag a `TextBox` and move it around on a `Canvas`, but [AllowDrop property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.allowdrop(v=vs.110).aspx) is for Drag-and-Drop operation. Drag-and-Move and Drag-and-Drop are different operations.

This is [an example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/442276/Drag-and-drop-WPF-controls) to do what you want.

The idea is handling the `MouseMove` event of the Canvas, calculating the position of the mouse cursor, and by setting the position of the `TextBox` to that position, you can make the `TextBox` move following the mouse cursor.